# How to remove all installation of opencv from fedora 17?

Tags: uninstall, fedora-17, opencv

I want to remove opencv from my fedora. I installed it from scratch by compiling it. It was loaded to /usr/local directory but distributed to all folders inside. Is there any special command or something to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go to the folder that I created before for installation inside opencv installation folder. Then I type `sudo make uninstall`.